# Доступ к файлу nosql

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Решили в проекте впервые попробовать nosql базу mongodb. Возник вопрос,если одновременно в файл json будет по api mongodb его запрос на выборку и запрос на update, что получит тот,кто делает выборку?Нужно ли работать с потоками, или там все из под коробки?

Comment: Интересно, вы чем руководствовались, когда "решили попробовать" ? Обычно перед принятием таких важных решений по проекту изучают документацию по используемой СУБД (по возможности всю). Первый же запрос гуглу говорит что операции атомарны. так что читающий поврежденный документ точно не получит. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-atomic-operations/ так что читающий увидит или старый документ или уже новый, смотря когда пройдет его запрос.

Comment: Очень надеюсь, что вы очень внимательно рассмотрели все вопросы работы вашего будущего проекта и действительно убедились, что ваши данные не реляционны по своей природе ... https://habr.com/post/231213/